# Moksha on putrada ekadashi

Tags: vaishnavism, moksha, rebirth, ekadashi

My Dad expired on Putrada ekadhashi will get get Moksha or rebirth? What can I do to give him sadgati if he has not attained moksha?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.